# How to list .hpp header files as they are being built with CMake

Tags: c++, build, cmake, output

I have a number of C++ header files that don't have an implementation file and are self-contained. Each of these files end with `.hpp`, in standing with one of my conventions.

When I compile my project now it only lists(via `stdout`) the the `.cpp` that are being built, but not any of the `.hpp` files. So how can I list the `.hpp` files as they are being built? I am using CMake 3.13, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linux answer:**

Remember Cmake does not compile, although you can do `cmake --build .` , this works just as as calling `make` in the folder where you ran the `cmake ../.. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG`. So Cmake is just a build generator but not an actual builder.
The `make` command also doesn't build, it just reads some script/text files (let's call them this for simplicity) and in them it has the rules to invoke the desired compiler (GCC, CLANG, etc). So the headers are shown at the precompilation phase by the compiler. That is handled by the compiler. So if you want to see all the headers included you need to tell the compiler to show them to you
Try and add -M as a [compiler flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) (i assumed that you are compiling with GCC)

> Instead of outputting the result of preprocessing, output a rule
>   suitable for make describing the dependencies of the main source file.
>   The preprocessor outputs one make rule containing the object file name
>   for that source file, a colon, and the names of all the included
>   files, including those coming from -include or -imacros command line
>   options.

A smaller output flag would be **-H**

> -H Print the name of each header file used, in addition to other normal activities. Each name is indented to show how deep in the
>   ‘#include’ stack it is. Precompiled header files are also printed,
>   even if they are found to be invalid; an invalid precompiled header
>   file is printed with ‘...x’ and a valid one with ‘...!’ .

Comment: Thanks for the answer @eucristian! If no one presents an answer soon I will accept it, sorry to make you wait.

Comment: I tried it, but it outputs ***ALL*** the header files that are linked, is there anyway to only do local headers? I assume not.

Comment: Try -MM or look in the link that I gave to you. -MM does not output system header I think

Comment: Ok, so I tried adding it to CMake(I was using a test file and g++/clang) with the both the `add_compile_options` and `target_compile_definitions` functions, but the output seems to be suppressed, something with CMake's generation of the make file, I guess. Any thoughts? Also, sorry, I should have looked in the link.

Comment: use make VERBOSE=1 instead of cmake --build

Comment: Thanks @eucristian, that worked, you my want to add what is in the comments to your answer.